# how to send data to mysqli with an index number (prepared statement)

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I am creating an array from dynamic created input fields and then send the array over to php, in php I create a foreach loop and try to insert it into my database.

I have created a foreach loop for my array and insert the values like that in my database, however my problem is: You cannot bind a variable with an index number to your query string. I have already verified whether it's actually an array what I am sending and the answer is: Yes. it is an array.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO vv(event_id, vvType, vvCosting) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
foreach ($example as $index => $value) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $id, $example, $example_costs);

    $id = $id;
    $example = $value;
    $example_costs = example_costs[$index]; //this DOES NOT work
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

So what I want would be the following: Create one foreach loop for my `$example` variable and based on the index numbers it has also insert the data from the variable `example_costs` and insert that in the database as well. You shouldn't worry about whether the index value exists or not in my `example_costs` variable, since they're "pairs".

I know the problem is that I cannot bind my variable like this:

```
$example_costs[$index]
```

So now my question is: How can I bind my variable like the above? But in a way php DOES accept? Or do I need to create 2 foreach loops? --> Something I would rather NOT do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what exactly you mean by "doesn't work" (i.e. you didn't describe what is going wrong or what behaviour you're seeing), but here's what I can observe just from the code:

1) You have (what appears to be) a typo: I expect `example_costs[$index];` should really be `$example_costs[$index];`.

2) Assuming 1 is fixed, you're also overwriting the values of the variables `$example` and `$example_costs`, which are the ones you're trying to loop over, whilst the loop is still going on. Clearly this will destroy the original arrays and make them impossible to re-use next time it tries to loop.

In this situation, and as a general point of good coding practice, don't re-use variable names to represent two different things in the code - especially when you are still in the middle of using them for their original purpose!

In reality you don't really need these separate variables in the bind statement anyway. This should do the job:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO vv(event_id, vvType, vvCosting) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
foreach ($example as $index => $value) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $id, $value, $example_costs[$index]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

The rest is either incorrect (over-writing the `$example` array, for instance) or redundant (`$id = $id` for instance - assigning a variable its own value is the very definition of pointless).

Comment: Well, i'd rather have a pointless variable at the moment then instantly jump to practices where I am assuming. Rather some clarification for myself so to speak. However I noticed you stated the following: $example_costs[$index]. but is this valid? Considering I am still applying a index number to it aswell, right?

Comment: I tried your code and it works, but is this because I was overwriting the old value (array) from the variable to something new?

Comment: `example_costs[$index].` is perfectly valid assuming `example_costs` is an array. This is true anywhere in PHP, it has nothing to do with parameter binding at all. the bind_param method is not special, you can pass any value to it, just like you can with any other function. I'm not clear what your confusion is here, really? Your problem before was forgetting the `$` at the start of the variable name.

Comment: "this because I was overwriting the old value (array) from the variable to something new?" Yes. That's my point. Let's say $example was `array(0 => "Value 0", 1 => "Value 1");` . If during the loop, you do what you were doing and write `$example = $value;`...then at that moment $example becomes a string containing "Value 0". So when you then get to the start of the `foreach` loop again, and it tries to look up the next value in the $example array, it finds the array is actually now a string, and therefore clearly it cannot choose the next array value...because it does not exist any more.

Comment: I noticed, as you pointed out, I destroyed the variable which held the array, by assiging a new value to it. Therefore it turned into a string and it then tried to find the index of the character I assume. The error stated was: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1. Thanks for helping out and pointing out the mistake I made.